# How to parse text from html file

Tags: python

```
import urllib2
import nltk
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup




l = """<TR><TD><small style=font-family:courier> >M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv3676|crp<br />VDEILARAGIFQGVEPSAIAALTKQLQPVDFPRGHTVFAEGEPGDRLYIIISGKVKIGRR<br />APDGRENLLTIMGPSDMFGELSIFDPGPRTSSATTITEVRAVSMDRDALRSWIADRPEIS<br />EQLLRVLARRLRRTNNNLADLIFTDVPGRVAKQLLQLAQRFGTQEGGALRVTHDLTQEEI<br />AQLVGASRETVNKALADFAHRGWIRLEGKSVLISDSERLARRAR<br /></small><TR><td><b><big>Blastp: <a href="http://tuberculist.epfl.ch/blast_output/Rv3676.fasta.out"> Pre-computed results</a></big></b><TR><td><b><big>TransMembrane prediction using Hidden Markov Models: <a href="http://tuberculist.epfl.ch/tmhmm/Rv3676.html"> TMHMM</a></big></b><base target="_blank"/><TR><td><b><big>Genomic sequence</big></b><br /><br /><form action="dnaseq.php" method="get">"""

print l
```

I have one HTML line and want to extract the text which is embedded into the HTML tags. I have tried with all the available methods, but they are not working in my case.

How can I do it?

Expected output should be:

H37Rv|Rv3676|crp
VDEILARAGIFQGVEPSAIAALTKQLQPVDFPRGHTVFAEGEPGDRLYIIISGKVKIGRRAPDGRENLLTIMGPSDMFGELSIFDPGPRTSSATTITEVRAVSMDRDALRSWIADRPEISEQLLRVLARRLRRTNNNLADLIFTDVPGRVAKQLLQLAQRFGTQEGGALRVTHDLTQEEIAQLVGASRETVNKALADFAHRGWIRLEGKSVLISDSERLARRAR

Comment: You will find very good examples of what you are trying to do here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you import BeautifulSoup, so you can use BeautifulSoup to help you extract these information.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(l,"html.parser")
print soup.get_text()
```

I've tried and it worked, but the sentence in the last tag will also be extracted, you have to cut the result if needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
try: 
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = BeautifulSoup(l)
small = html.find_all('small')
print (small.get_text())
```

This gets the small tag and prints out all the text in it

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with BeautifulSoup which was not working for me because it was producing unformatted version so i have decide to write down code with my self and its working absolutely fine and  producing what i want.

```
import urllib2


proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://******************'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
res = urllib2.urlopen('http://tuberculist.epfl.ch/quicksearch.php?gene+name=Rv3676')
html = res.readlines()

for l in html:


    if "Genomic sequence" in l:
        l = l.split("</small>")[0]

        l  = l.split("<br />")
        header = l[0]
        sequence = l[1:]

        print "".join([">", header.split(">")[4]])
        print "".join(sequence)
```

output

```
>M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv3676|crp


VDEILARAGIFQGVEPSAIAALTKQLQPVDFPRGHTVFAEGEPGDRLYIIISGKVKIGRRAPDGRENLLTIMGPSDMFGELSIFDPGPRTSSATTITEVRAVSMDRDALRSWIADRPEISEQLLRVLARRLRRTNNNLADLIFTDVPGRVAKQLLQLAQRFGTQEGGALRVTHDLTQEEIAQLVGASRETVNKALADFAHRGWIRLEGKSVLISDSERLARRAR
```